# Unificar consulta SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo un código que es el siguiente:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2016/12/31 23:59:59'
DELETE FROM EntradaVTP && SalidaVTP  
WHERE id in (
    SELECT id
    FROM Solicitud 
    WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion <= @DATE
)
```

Una vez acabe esto tendría que lanzarme lo siguiente: `Delete from Solicitud where FechaCreacion <= @DATE`

Hay alguna forma de ponerlo en el código con Select para que no sea una linea más, es decir poder incorporarlo al código? Es decir que el código este más unificado, pero el problema es que Solicitud no puedo borrarlo el primero hasta que no borre lo otro.. Por eso mi duda.

Comment: no puedes borrar datos de 2 tablas diferentes en un solo `DELETE`

Comment: no entiendo eso de 'ponerlo en codigo con select' puedes explicar mas lo que esperas?

Comment: Básicamente si se puede borrar dos cosas en el mismo delete.. pero ya me ha contestado alguien que es imposible.

Comment: Básicamente evitar esto: DELETE FROM EntradaVTP WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion <= @DATE);
DELETE FROM SalidaVTP WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion <= @DATE);
DELETE FROM SolicitudVTP WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM Solicitud WHERE Solicitud.FechaCreacion <= @DATE);

Comment: Tal vez si explicas porque querrias hacer algo asi (que no sea son menos lineas) podrian darte alguna alternativa...

Comment: Y porque duplicaste tu pregunta?